# is this the cleanest approach for :has_many association to STI models in a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, single-table-inheritance

The following works, but is it the cleanest approach?

In short, a Project :has_many Tasks.  Tasks are represented by an STI table and different subclasses of tasks are in the Task:: module (and subdirectory):

```
# schema
create_table projects do |t|
  # t.integer :id  - implicitly generated
end
create_table task_bases do |t|
  # t.integer :id  - implicitly generated
  t.string    :type        # for STI support
  t.integer   :project_id
end

# file: app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  :has_many :tasks, :class_name => "Task::Base", :dependent => :destroy
end

# file: app/models/task.rb
module Task
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "task_"
  end
end

# file: app/models/task/base.rb
module Task
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    :belongs_to :project
  end
end

# file app/models/task/priority.rb
module Task
  class Priority < Base
    :belongs_to :project
  end
end
```

A couple of questions:

- Task::Base should never be instantiated -- we'll only use sub-classes of it.  I think this means that I declare it as an abstract_class -- what's the proper way to do that?
- Would it be better to name the STI table `tasks` rather than `task_bases`, and if so, what other changes need to happen?
- Should I be troubled by the `:class_name => "Task::Base"` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the above works.  But in the common case that you have a Task:: module, a Task::Base class and several sub-classes of Task::Base, the following is cleaner:

### define your STI table using the module name

```
create_table task_bases do |t|
  # t.integer :id  - implicitly generated
  t.string    :type        # for STI support
  t.integer   :project_id
end
```

### create app/models/`<module_name>`.rb

This file simply includes all the files in the `<module_name>` subdirectory:

```
# file: app/models/task.rb
module Task
  require 'task/base'  # comment out unless task/base.rb must be loaded first
  Dir[Rails.root.join("app/models/task/**/*.rb").to_s].each {|f| require f}
end
```

### create app/models/`<module_name>`/base.rb

Put any functionality that's common to all subclasses here.  Note that this is where we define the STI table name.

```
# file: app/models/task/base.rb
module Task
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'tasks'
    # include common functionality here
  end
end
```

### create any subclasses you need.

```
# file: app/models/task/batch.rb
module Task
  class Batch < Base
    # batch specific code here
  end
end
# file: app/models/task/sequential.rb
module Task
  class Sequential < Base
    # sequential specific code here
  end
end
```